# Как преобразовать базу данных Access в формат mdb?

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, access

Создал я базу данных в формате *accdb и пытаюсь подключить ее к своей программе, но дело в том что такой формат не поддерживается, в документации написано как подключить БД в таком формате, но у меня нет последних пунктов как в там, поэтому я перешел ко 2-ому варианту, это преобразование в *mdb, но тут еще одна проблема, что  новые фичи не поддерживаются в формате *mdb, подскажите что делать, БД не маленькая переписывать не хочется.
Вот что выводит при попытке преобразовать в формат *mdb 
[image: Сохранение БД]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что у меня не было данного поставщика: «Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0»
Решение проблемы мне помогла статья:
[OLEDB 12.0](http://www.nookery.ru/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-error/)

Answer (score 0):

В Access попробуй так : Файл- Сохранить как- выбираешь нужный тип - Нажимаешь сохранить как- выбираешь место и имя. Посмотри что не работает, сильно ли критично. Данные и связи по крайней мере точно сохраняться

Comment: он даже не дает указать имя и место, единственное решение для себя которое я нашел, это экспорт каждой таблицы в БД с форматом *mdb